# Updating the Custom Object - Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I got stuck and now sure what I'm doing wrong here:

here is my trigger:

```
trigger EmployeeTrigger on Employee__c (after insert, before update) 
{
    EmployeeController mr = new EmployeeController();
    mr.EmployeeController(Trigger.new);
}
```

Apex class:

```
List<Employee__c> Employees = new List<Employee__c>();
List<Employee__c> empList = [SELECT Id, Name, Employee_Name__c
                                     FROM Employee__c 
                                     WHERE Employee_Id__c = 123456 ];

for(Employee__c pm : empList)
{
   pm.Current_City__c = 'timbaktu';
   Employees.Add(pm);
}
update Employees;
```

> Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger
>   EmployeeTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: EmployeeTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate
>   caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object: Class.EmployeeController.EmployeeController:
>   line 147, column 1

Comment: You should identify which line is line 147 in your question. I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause an NPE.

Comment: triggers invoking controllers ...not best practice - there is no VF context when calling a VF controller object from a trigger

Comment: Keith: its failing on 'update Employees'

Comment: Crop: I am not sure I understand

Comment: ... are you sure there isn't any logic that could set `Employees` to null between where you declare and initialise it and the update?

Comment: yes I'm sure and I have hard-coded the value just to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.... but what is that error is that due to initializing the class or null value?

Comment: OK if `Employees` isn't null then I guess the problem must be in an update trigger on Employee__c; check any such triggers. (I though such an error would be reported differently though.) That error is typically when you invoke a method on an object reference that is null, though I did check that you get it with e.g. `Contact[] cs = null;update cs;`.

Comment: sorry Abu, I assumed `EmployeeController` was a VF controller due to its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If line 147 has `pm.Current_City__c = 'timbaktu';`, then you probably have this issue because the field `Current_City__c` was not included in the query.